Detrending Time Series Data for Network Analysis
In order to run psychometric network analyses on (up to) 10 repeated measures for 13 variables in R, I need to detrend my 13 variables (B1 to B13) first. My problem is that not all subjects (id) have 10 measurements and i'm not sure if i should take my time variable (week) as a factor in order to not be bothered with linearity and stuff. Does anyone have some suggestion for good documentation on this subject or some link to some sample code?
